# strtotime PHP function questions

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a strtotime function that is doing something like this:

```
$var = strtotime('23:59:59' . $Date);
```

Where `$Date` is a date in this format:  `MM/DD/YY`

However, this randomly fails and returns nothing from it....  am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's the issue in your case, but be aware of the potential amiguity between MM/DD/YY and DD/MM/YY. As stated in the manual page for strtotime(), you are better off using [`createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) if you know the format of the string in advance.

Comment: This question showed no effort to research and self-solve.  This question will have no value for future SO readers who know how to read the manual on `strtotime` and how to check the data they are feeding into it.  Please delete this useless question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a space character to the end of your time string

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily always the best way to accomplish date math, but note the very handy feature that strtotime() takes interval words too:

```
$var = strtotime($date . ' +1 day -1 second');
```

I.e., start at $date, add one day, then subtract one second. This gives you 23:59:59 for $date.